# How to display reasult after api request? (js)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement the good reads API with the search but I can make the request but I don't know how to display it. I tried to find tutorials there were none.

Edit - Got it to work thanks all <3

app.js

```
var input = document.querySelector('.input_text');
var main = document.querySelector('#name');
var temp = document.querySelector('.author');
var desc = document.querySelector('.title');
var button= document.querySelector('.button');


document
  .querySelector('input[type="button"]')
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
  const input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;  fetch("https://v1.nocodeapi.com/lap/gr/ZXOgJZwIXeGBhScd/search?q=" + input)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(data => {
     console.log(data)
  var nameValue = data['obj_id'];
  var descValue = data['reasults'][0]['title'];

  reasults.innerHTML = nameValue;
  desc.innerHTML = "Desc - "+descValue;
  input.value ="";
  
})

})
```

html

```
 <div class="input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the city" class="input_text">
      <input type="button" value="button" class="button">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <h1 class="name" id="name"></h1>
      <p class="type"></p>
      <p class="title"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

sorry for confusing code first time using apis
Thank you so much :).

Comment: you would do so in another `.then(data => { do things here because the data is available here })` after `.then(response => response.json())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing almost everything right, however there is one small thing. When you use the `json( )` function on the `Promise.prototype.then( )'s` `response`, the result is again a Promise. That is just how it works, therefore you will need to use the `Promise.prototype.then( )` function again on the result to get the actual data. Like below:

```
    button.addEventListener("click", function (name) {
  fetch(
    "https://v1.nocodeapi.com/lap/gr/ZXOgJZwIXeGBhScd/search?q=" + input.value
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
});
```

Here's an example showing the same:

```js
document
  .querySelector('input[type="button"]')
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
  const input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;  fetch("https://v1.nocodeapi.com/lap/gr/ZXOgJZwIXeGBhScd/search?q=" + input)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  });
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from the API is within `response.json()`. So to check youre getting the desired response you can try doing this and checking the console.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(name){
fetch('https://v1.nocodeapi.com/lap/gr/ZXOgJZwIXeGBhScd/search?q='+input.value)
.then(response => response.json()).then(data=>console.log(data))
})
```

Once you've verified that it is what you're expecting your next goal would be to display the data on the page. For this look at the structure of the response and decide what all you're going to be displaying. You could then use a function to generate the required HTML and then append it as a child into a node on your page.

You can either build everything as a string inserting the data wherever required and then set the container nodes `.innerHTML` to the string you've constructed.

Alternatively you could make all the nodes using commands like `document.createElement("div")` structure it the way you want and use `.appendChild`to display it on the page

Comment: The `json( )` function's return value is a promise. So he will not be able to see the contents inside with a `console.log(response.json( ))` unless he uses the `Promise.prototype.then( )` on the `Promise` returned by the `response.json( )` call.

Comment: Hi i have updated the question still cant get it to disp

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ajax in this way, if you are not fetching a single row you need to loop your data

```
$.get("url",function(data,status){
     var list = JSON.parse(data);
       //only loop for more than one row
      for(var  i = 0; i<list.lenvth; i++){
             document.getElementById('title').innerHTML  = list[i].title;
       }
});
```